# .grd file to GeoTIFF file

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, osgeo4w

I am trying to transform some data that I have that are in a .grd format and calculate something and then save again as a .grd or as a GeoTIFF. The problem is the projection, I cannot find the projection in order to save the data. I will provide the code that I try to fix:

```
def getgrd2(filename):
griddummy = -32767
i16 = 'int16'
i32 = 'int32'
f64 = 'float64'

with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    es = np.fromfile(f, dtype=i32, count=1)[0]
    sf = np.fromfile(f, dtype=i32, count=1)[0]
    ne = np.fromfile(f, dtype=i32, count=1)[0]
    nv = np.fromfile(f, dtype=i32, count=1)[0]
    kx = np.fromfile(f, dtype=i32, count=1)[0]
    de = np.fromfile(f, dtype=f64, count=1)[0]
    dv = np.fromfile(f, dtype=f64, count=1)[0]
    x0 = np.fromfile(f, dtype=f64, count=1)[0]
    y0 = np.fromfile(f, dtype=f64, count=1)[0]
    rot = np.fromfile(f, dtype=f64, count=1)[0]
    zbase = np.fromfile(f, dtype=f64, count=1)[0]
    zmult = np.fromfile(f, dtype=f64, count=1)[0]
    label = np.fromfile(f, dtype='S48', count=1).astype(str)[0].strip()
    mapno = np.fromfile(f, dtype='S16', count=1).astype(str)[0].strip()
    print(f'{es=}')
    print(f'{sf=}')
    print(f'{ne=}')
    print(f'{nv=}')
    print(f'{kx=}')
    print(f'{de=}')
    print(f'{dv=}')
    print(f'{x0=}')
    print(f'{y0=}')
    print(f'{rot=}')
    print(f'{zbase=}')
    print(f'{zmult=}')
    print(f'{label=}')
    print(f'{mapno=}')

    f.seek(512)
    raw_matrix = (
        np
        .fromfile(f, dtype=i16, count=ne * nv)
        .reshape(nv, ne)
        )
    # convert -32767 values to nan before rescaling
    # raw_matrix's type becomes float64 in the process
    raw_matrix = np.where(raw_matrix == griddummy, np.nan, raw_matrix)
    # rescale and offset the values back to their original range, and position
    matrix = raw_matrix/zmult + zbase

    dummy = np.nanmin(raw_matrix) #???

    Xaxis = np.arange(x0, x0 + de * ne, de)
    Yaxis = np.arange(y0, y0 + dv * nv, dv)

    print(de, dv)
    if kx == 1:
    # kx means the original matrix was transposed, we swap the axis as well
        matrix = matrix.T
        #Xaxis, Yaxis = Yaxis, Xaxis
    elif kx != -1:
        raise ValueError("kx not valid")

x_tl, y_tl = np.min(Xaxis), np.max(Yaxis)
x_res, y_res = de, -dv

geot = np.array([x_tl, x_res, 0, y_tl, 0, y_res])


return matrix, Xaxis, Yaxis, dummy, geot



@dataclass
class Metadata:
kx: int = -1 # 1 to store the matrix transposed
rot: int = 0
label: str = ''
mapno: str = ''
proj:int = 0
unitx:int = 0
unity:int = 0
unitz:int = 0

izmin:int = 0
izmax:int = 0
izmed:int = 0
izmea:int = 0
zvar:int = 0
prcs:int = 0



def export_geosoftgrd(geo_file, matrix, x, y, metadata=None):
metadata = metadata or Metadata()

# some file format constants it seems
es = 2
sf = 1
griddummy = -32767 # NaN value
maxconst = 29490 # max range to use for int16

x0, y0 = x[0], y[0]
de, dv = x[1] - x[0], y[1] - y[0]
nv, ne = matrix.shape
nvpts = ne*nv

dmin = np.nanmin(matrix)
dmax = np.nanmax(matrix)

# what happens here is a change of value range so that floats can be stored
# as int16 while limiting the loss of information
# so that if values go from -1.5 to 4.0, it'll go from -29490 to 29490
# to that effect the range of values will be centered around their middle point
# between dmin and dmax, and scaled to occupy the whole range

# using that example, the middle value will be (-1.5 + 4.0) / 2 = 1.25
# so by moving all the values by -1.25, we get a range of
# [-1.5-1.25, 4-1.25] = [-2.75, 2.75]

# dmax - zbase will be 2.75, the highest difference to the middle
# so zmult = 29490 / 2.75 = 10723.636363636364
# so if we multiply all the values by that amount, the range will become
# [-2.75 * zmult, 2.75 * zmult] = [-29490, 29490]

# when importing that data back, we'll get the original value
# (well almost, we'll still incur a slight loss of information)
# by inverting that computation, first dividing by zmult to go back to the right
# scale of value, and then offseting back by zbase

#zbase = 0
zbase= (dmin + dmax)/2
zmult = maxconst / (dmax - zbase)
matrix = (matrix - zbase) * zmult
matrix[np.isnan(matrix)] = griddummy

label_size = 48
metadata.label = metadata.label.ljust(label_size)[:label_size]
mapno_size = 16
metadata.mapno = metadata.mapno.ljust(mapno_size)[:mapno_size]

with open(geo_file, 'wb') as fid:
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', es))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', sf))
    if metadata.kx == 1:
    # swap everything if transposed
        fid.write(struct.pack('<i', nv))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<i', ne))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<i', 1))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<d', dv))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<d', de))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<d', y0))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<d', x0))
    else:
        fid.write(struct.pack('<i', ne))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<i', nv))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<i', -1))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<d', de))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<d', dv))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<d', x0))
        fid.write(struct.pack('<d', y0))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<d', metadata.rot))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<d', zbase))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<d', zmult))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<48s', metadata.label.encode('ascii')))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<16s', metadata.mapno.encode('ascii')))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', metadata.proj))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', metadata.unitx))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', metadata.unity))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', metadata.unitz))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', nvpts))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', metadata.izmin))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', metadata.izmax))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', metadata.izmed))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<i', metadata.izmea))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<d', metadata.zvar))
    fid.write(struct.pack('<d', metadata.prcs))

    fid.seek(512)
    matrix = matrix.astype('int16')
    if metadata.kx == 1:
        # to store the matrix transposed we iterate on the x first
        for x in range(ne):
            for y in range(nv):
                fid.write(struct.pack('<h', matrix[y, x]))
    else:
        for y in range(nv):
            for x in range(ne):
                fid.write(struct.pack('<h', matrix[y, x]))
```

I provide the metadata that I use as well as the the exporter that I build also in order to export my data after I finish.

Comment: can you confirm which format your .grd files are, do you mean Arc/Info ASCII Grid for example.

Comment: @nmtoken the .grd file comes from Geosoft program

Comment: Can you run gdalinfo on your grid file and post the results?

Comment: I cannot run gdalinfo, but I can send a pic of the hexdump @GBG